# Current context and databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I try to use a databinding in a Xamarin Application List.
I am following : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/.
Visual Studio give me this error : CS0103  C# The name "ELementView" does not exist in the current context.
I think it is a problem about the xmlns:local in xaml fil but I don't know.

Xaml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App4;assembly=listeElements"
             x:Class="App4.Page1"
             Title="ListView Demo Page">

    <ListView x:Name="ELementView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

listeElements code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App4
{
    public class Element
    {
        private string element;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return element; }
            set { element = value; }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Element> Elements = new ObservableCollection<Element>();
        public void ElementListPage()
        {
            ELementView.ItemsSource = Elements;
            Elements.Add(new Element { Name = "oooo" });
        }
    }



};
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: There's some code somewhere that tries to reference `"ELementView"`. Can we see that? In context?

Comment: your Xaml is App4.Page1, your code is App4.Element.  The codebehind file for a XAML page should share the same classname and inherit from the same base type (ContentPage).  Typically when you create a new XAML page in the IDE it will do all of this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use this:

```
public Page1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Elemenet e = new Element();
   e.ElementListPage();
   this.BindingContext = e;
}
```

but make sure your `ObservableCollection<Element>` has `{get; set;}`;

Then you can add an `ItemsSource`-Binding to your `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
```

as you definded the `DataContext` for `Page1` it will look for a Property called Elements in your DataContext (which is the class Element) - there it gets the ElementsCollection and adds the `Name` to your `CellTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

Just by giving the `ListView` a name doesn't mean you can reference it from anywhere. You can now reference `ELementView` from the code-behind of your `Page1` XAML page.

To get there, open your Solution window, go to `Page1.xaml` click the arrow to the left of it and double-click `Page1.xaml.cs`.

In this page you could do something like this:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

public Page1()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   ObservableCollection<Element> Elements = new ObservableCollection<Element>();

   ELementView.ItemsSource = Elements;
   Elements.Add(new Element { Name = "oooo" });
}
```

Although this would work, it probably isn't the best approach. You are trying to use MVVM which is good! But you can take it a step further.

Maybe try using a MVVM framework like MvvmCross or FreshMvvm. I have done a blogpost on the later. You can find it [here](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/beauty-and-the-beast-use-mvvm-to-unleash-inner-beauty/). Although new versions have come out, this should get you started with the basics.